# filesystem layer verification failed for digest

Tags: docker

How to fix the docker problem?
when I use the latest EC2 and docker (1.9.1)
whatever the image is, they always tell me this error:
"""
filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256
"""

What should I do?

Comment: I had pretty much the same issue, but for me it occured when I was pulling and verifying multiple images at the same time. I guess that is not the case in your scenario? For me it resolved when I stopped pulling in images in parallel.

Answer (score 6):

That looks like an [error from a trusted sandbox](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/trust_sandbox/).
But it has been seen in other context, like [issue 15603](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15603)

Try and [stop/restart the docker daemon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html), and remove all images

```
 sudo service docker stop
 sudo service docker start
 docker images -q | xargs docker rmi
```

Answer (score 0):

I am run into this problem when running ubuntu on virtualbox, finally I found it may because of the virtualbox software has broken. After reinstall virtualbox, everything is ok(VM created before is still working, no need to crate new VM).

**More info**

at same time, when I run:

```
apt update
```

I get this error:

```
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:03a16e592ababd5fbd11dc5c90503f166340d0f87efd69315892151df20f0a6a
   - Filesize:18208700 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:cf0461e3778f9765def3cdd527b66d477602b890c3bf0672376e7c3f41285c46
   - Filesize:18208700 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Fri, 10 Jun 2022 03:36:01 +0000
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved removing the content of /var/lib/docker/ (but attention!! in this way you will remove all images, containers, and configurations)

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
```

then

```
service docker stop
service docker start
```