# All public image pulls fail with “filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256”

Tags: docker

I've tried this on at least 5 different versions of Linux and always hit the same wall:

I can use docker to run hello-world successfully. But whenever I try to pull any other image (e.g. ubuntu, nginx) it pulls the pieces in parallel and then ends up with the filesystem layer verification failure.  Has anyone seen this problem or can offer advice?

Components:

- CentOS 7.3.1611 (3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64) as a Virtual Box VM
- Docker 1.10.3
- xfs file system

Configuration steps (CentOS):

```
  # yum install docker  

  # systemctl start docker
  # systemctl status docker
  # systemctl enable docker

  # docker run hello-world  (works)
  # docker pull ubuntu      (fails)
```

<sup>*Note: Yum doesn't install docker 1.12 if I try to manually there are conflicts.*</sup>

---

Current questions:

---

1. Are there issues with docker in a Virtualbox guest host?
2. Does Docker require a specify type of filesystem?
3. I read a comment somewhere that fails when trying to pull multiple
   pieces in parallel (hello-world is a single chunk), but I can't
   verify that. Is there another tiny image I can try?
4. The only issues I've seen relate to AWS and I'm not using AWS. Could
   it be a SHA key issue?

Answer to comment:
Note: I can run the hello-world example and busybox.  The are both one layer.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it.sudo docker pull debian
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/debian ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/debian
75a822cd7888: Verifying Checksum 
filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:75a822cd7888e394c49828b951061402d31745f596b1f502758570f2d0ee79e2
filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256:75a822cd7888e394c49828b951061402d31745f596b1f502758570f2d0ee79e2

Comment: People here get pretty busy and the quicker you can identify the specifics of the technical problem, the better. Essay style usually isn't appreciated, particularly for a long question. Most people are frustrated by the time they post here, tried a lot of things, wish they didn't have to ask, etc... :-). I edited the question. If you think it's an improvement, you can keep the edit otherwise you can revert it or further edit it.

Comment: SO is about programming.  This sounds more like a sys adm. issue. I like http://unix.stackexchange.com/ and there are other exchange sites that would be more appropriate.  You might get better responses from those sites.

Comment: Have you tried both ways described in the official [Docker installation documentation for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/)? Can you please cut&paste the exact error messages?

Comment: See also this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448975/filesystem-layer-verification-failed-for-digest

Comment: Olli - Yes.  I've tried both ways, tried Ubuntu 16.  Same issue every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Virtualbox bug. It makes sense, since every machine I was trying this on was a Virtualbox VM (see original post). In investigating a work-around to download the pieces manually via wget, wget was getting errors on all machines. Downloads over a few seconds were throwing "SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac". Googling that showed that this is a known (as of 2014 anyway) bug in Virtualbox when the VM's network type is set to Bridged. **The solution is to set the network type in the VM to NAT.**