# Issue with Docker on Linux (Ubuntu + Fedora): "filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker run hello-world works just fine, but when I try to pull with docker and docker-compose I get this error every time. I also tried Podman and had the same result. I tried this on fresh installs + VM of Fedora 33, 34, and Ubuntu 20.04lts.

`“filesystem layer verification failed for digest sha256: _ longhashvaluehere _”`

I found 5 or 6 other posts asking about this but no apparent answer. I have already tried the steps suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448975/filesystem-layer-verification-failed-for-digest).

Comment: are you connecting from a stable network ? is it behind a proxy ? 
if you are using a virtual machine, try to configure its network to NAT

Comment: Behavior has been the same in VMs. Just a regular home network and no proxy